# How to clean/sort data in R with multiple entries corresponding to few of the intermittent row variables under several columns?

Tags: mysql, r, excel, rstudio, data-cleaning

[the data sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdGui.jpg)How to clean/re-organize data in R/R Studio in case a row variable has more than one entries under the column variables ? e.g. I have a data-set that has 13 columns , and 14 rows, in each of the month tab of an excel workbook depicting a year, there are 5 workbooks like this. So, in total there are 5 * 12 = 60 tabs. In each of the month tab, before the second/third/ etc. row starts, the previous row already has multiple entries under a column head, like the one in the attached image at the beginning.

how to format/clean this whole data, including all the months in a year, and also accounting for 5 years on trot, and make this suitable for analysis ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: without any reproductible example , we cant help you...

Comment: I am not able to express the data here, it is like multiple entries for Row 2 under column 2, e.g. several invoice dates, then row 3 begins, with multiple entries under column 2 , then row 4 with one entry, in this manner ..

Comment: @ThinkR - I have attached an image at the beginning of my main post, plz have a look ..

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. You could clean, format and re-organise data in a number of different ways. If you show us what you have tried so far, it might help. Also, you can use `dput` over a subset of the data to share a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to import the excel data into R studio?

Look at the library "xlsx" in order to read excel sheets in.

This will be entered into your environment as a data frame. Available for you to analyse. If you want to have R studio recognise dates, then look at the library "lubridate".

You aren't particularly clear as to what you want here, after you've done some R coding, put it up, and we can help further.